# htacces redirect /olddir (domain.com)/newfile.xml

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the current dir from example.com/rss to example.com/rss.xml with htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^rss$ rss.xml [R=301]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens when you try to acees example.com/rss

Comment: When I try to visit 'example.com/rss' I get a 404 page because the page does not exists anymore

Comment: you mean rss.mxl doesn't exist in your server?If it's true ,so create it! otherwise, explain more please!

Comment: bit late with my reaction...
the old location was example.com/rss but the new location is rss.xml I don't want to create the old /rss I want to redirect to the new file.

Comment: remove [R=301] it's for external redirects. rss.xml should exist in your server(in directory where your .htaccess is)

Comment: thanx that seams to work! But i don't have the rss.xml in the directory where the .htaccess is. but it wil still work because of the way my server is set up. If you post your answer below I'll mark it as the answer so you can get the points for it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `[R=301]` it's for external redirects. `rss.xml` should exist in your server(in directory where your `.htaccess` is)